# Integrating non-continuous function

Tags: integration

f(x)=0 if $x \neq \frac{b-a}{2}$, and f(x)=3000 if $x=\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Find $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$.

How can this be done? I know how to calculate integrals using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but this doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: If $\frac{b-a}{2}$ is outside the interval $(a,b)$, then the integrand $f(x)$ is zero on the interval and the integral is zero. If $\frac{b-a}{2}$ is in the interval $(a,b)$, then split up the integral into the sum of two pieces: one on $\left(a,\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$ and the other on $\left(\frac{b-a}{2},b\right)$. On each interval, the integrand is zero again, so each integral evaluates to zero.

Comment: Why don't we consider the case when the function is equal to $\frac{b-a}{2}$ by using a half-open interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:"Value at a single point doesn't affect the integral". You can easily show this by the Riemann sum definition of an integral.

So the integral has to be $0$

Comment: Does showing this formally involve using the infimum and one of the sums?

Comment: @kiwifruit: Yes that's the idea. Take a partition. Now, the only partition that "matters" is the one containing the point where $f$ is non zero. So infs are all $0$. The sup is not- but then the sup will be arbitraily small as soon as the partitions have smaller size.

Comment: But if the function has the value 1000 for some x, why doesn't this mean the upper sum will be non-zero, and so will the integral?

Comment: @kiwifruit: the integral is the "limit" of upper sums. The limit grows small as soon as the size of each partition grows small.

Comment: Hmm, and if we had a function that was 1000 at all values, why wouldn't its integral also be 0, since each of the sums grows smaller?

Comment: @kiwifruit: It wouldn't be because all the sums would be equal to $1000$, no matter what your partition size- write it down and you will see.